# Styling a GoDaddy site seal in a Bootstrap 3 footer

Tags: css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two site seals that I am trying to make look nice in a simple footer, and the GoDaddy one just isn't playing nice like the Trustwave one is ie...

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="footer">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 ">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://sealserver.trustwave.com/seal.js?code=<?= $this->model->getTWKey() ?>"></script>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 ">
            <span id="cdSiteSeal2"><script type="text/javascript" src="//tracedseals.starfieldtech.com/siteseal/get?scriptId=cdSiteSeal2&amp;cdSealType=Seal2&amp;sealId=55e4ye7y7mb73952743bf753a95b7cfvma3y7mb7355e4ye734fda9346a2ed18a"></script></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I was thinking this would work but it doesn't look good to me ie

http://www.sageccpayment.com/index.php?id=4

It looks like the GoDaddy seal is padding the whole col-md-6 div or something.  I'm not a designer so I don't quite get what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to force the same height on the both divs and center the objects/images

Example

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="footer">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-center" style="height: 150px;">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://sealserver.trustwave.com/seal.js?code=<?= $this->model->getTWKey() ?>"></script>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 text-center" style="height: 150px;">
        <span id="cdSiteSeal2"><script type="text/javascript" src="//tracedseals.starfieldtech.com/siteseal/get?scriptId=cdSiteSeal2&amp;cdSealType=Seal2&amp;sealId=55e4ye7y7mb73952743bf753a95b7cfvma3y7mb7355e4ye734fda9346a2ed18a"></script></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```